# Did Littlefinger know about Ramsay Bolton?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 5, Littlefinger makes Sansa Stark marry Ramsay Bolton. Although Petyr Baelish is very manipulative and can be somewhat evil himself, I always believed he genuinely cared for Sansa. This then made me wonder: in Season 5, when Sansa is made to marry Ramsay, did Baelish know about Ramsay Bolton's sadistic, evil, and frankly psychopathic nature and what he could, and did, do to Sansa?

Comment: She asks him this very question and he appears to be really ignorant. Which isn't realistic - another problem with changes in plot done while adapting the books.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90112/whats-the-use-of-littlefingers-latest-shenanigans-season-5-episodes-67

Comment: @Mithoron wasn't there a subtle recurring theme in the books where, multiple times, he'd do elaborate manipulations motivated by his feelings for Catelyn that engulfed her in frightening chaos, then he'd seem _genuinely_ surprised that it hurt her and made her not happy? I have this vague memory of seeing the scene you refer to in the TV show and thinking something like "They're doing it clumsily, but I think they're trying to echo how, in the books, his sociopathic limited empathy becomes an obstacle to getting his way because he's blind to how he harms the people he uses"

Comment: @user My point is he is it the business of *knowing*. There's no way he wouldn't. Oh, he hurt Sansa a lot in the books already, but not because of incompetence.

Comment: @Mithoron yes, that is precisely why I asked the question. Knowing his character, it seemed like he should have known. This then conflict with how, in the TV show at least, he's shown to have some genuine care and affection for sansa.

Comment: Well, that's why I called it a problem with changes in plot done while adapting the books. In the books it was Jeyne Poole impersonating Arya - they didn't care what's gonna happen. Putting Sansa in her shoes reduced number of characters, but left Littlefinger suddenly ignorant of stuff he definitely should know. It's hardly a big thing in comparison with other shortcomings of later seasons, though.